# jquery function trasforms "@" sign into "Q "

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

I have I keyup function with which I want to detect whether the last entered characted is "@".

Function:

```
 $("#message").keyup(function (event) {
            var last_one=String.fromCharCode(event.which); 
            console.log(last_one)
            if(last_one == "@"){
                console.log("there you go")
            }
        })
```

When '@' sign is entered to the textfield the "last_one" appears as Q   on the console and two boxes appear on separate rows after a short delay. I tried to check for the boxes `if(last_one == "box-sign")` but that didn't work.

Comment: use event.key instead of String.fromCharCode(event.which); In my testing, I never saw a q. What platform and browser are you testing on?

Comment: thank you a lot but that returns @ 1:367 Control 1:367 AltGraph on console and still doesn't trigger the if part of the function.

Comment: What platform and browser are you testing on. It works for me in ubuntu 20.04 on chrome.

Comment: windows/chrome-opera-edge, it works for keydown btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** Scroll down!

You could make use of the `.slice();` function in JavaScript to get the last character of your string.

**Example:**

```
$('#message').on("keyup", function() {
    var str = $(this).val();
    var lastChar = str.slice(-1);

    if(lastChar == "@") {
      alert('There you go!');
    }
});
```

The `.slice();` function basically takes the length of the string and subtracts 1 in the index in this case, which then becomes the last character of your string. Then all you have to do is make your conditional.

**Snippet:**

```js
$('#message').on("keyup", function() {
 var str = $(this).val();
 var lastChar = str.slice(-1);

 if(lastChar == "@") {
   alert('There you go!');
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
 <div class="col-6">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="enter string" />
 </div>
</div>
```

Codepen example [here](https://codepen.io/mbacode/pen/dyGNgQJ).

**EDIT:**

If you want to check if the @ sign is present anywhere within the string, then you can use the `.indexOf();` function and build your conditional around that.

**Example:**

```
$('#message').on("keyup", function() {
    var str = $(this).val();

    if(str.indexOf("@") > -1) {
      alert('There you go!');
    }
});
```

Codepen Example [here](https://codepen.io/mbacode/pen/LYGxXNm).

**Snippet:**

```js
$('#message').on("keyup", function() {
 var str = $(this).val();

 if(str.indexOf("@") > -1) {
   alert('There you go!');
 }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
 <div class="col-6">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="enter string" />
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot @Martin but it only works if the character is at the end of the string.

Comment: You want to check if the character is at any index in the string?

Comment: Yes I         $('#message').on("keyup", function() {
            var lastChar= event.key
        
            if(lastChar == "@") {
              console.log('There you go!');
            }
        }); this one works fine. Thank you a lot for the help, appreciated.

Comment: Check Edited answer if you want to know if the @ sign appears at any location within the String. :)

Comment: You are the best!